# Is Judas in hell for eternity?

Tags: forgiveness, judas-iscariot

I am a Christian, but have a hard time forgiving evil people, but I know that's what the Lord commanded me to do " Love and forgive your enemies , do good to those who persecute you....'  ~ So, I do every day TRY to do this. I have no problem with sinners... my problem is with people who claim to be Christians and are backstabbers, greedy, racists, etc. --those are the people I have trouble loving !

But here is my question >>>  "GOD IS LOVE" ... Judas betrayed Jesus for 30 pieces of silver, but then he was SO upset with what he did, he publicly SHOUTED out " I have betrayed innocent blood" !! and he threw down the silver (didn't want it) and felt SO bad he killed HIMSELF !  ~~~ I am not very forgiving to backstabbers in my life, but even I would forgive somebody who had me killed for money IF then did the aforementioned  things Judas did, feeling so bad ! If I would forgive a 'judas' , wouldn't The Lord ???

Comment: Forgiveness has a healing effect on the heart it inhabits. Betrayal and bloodshed have a destructive effect on the hearts they inhabit.

Comment: If you have trouble forgiving backstabbers, then forgiving someone who attempts to murder you will be much more difficult.  Forgiveness is best practiced with the opportunities you have.  I have found it much easier to forgive when I also look for ways to encourage or edify the one who sinned against me.
Feeling bad about one's choices and repenting are two different things.

Comment: hell is not forever, the fire's lake is it

Answer (score 2):

**Is Judas in hell for eternity?**

No one knows for sure if Judas is in hell for eternity.

One thing is for sure, Our Lord himself had strong words about Judas Iscariot:

> Jesus replied, “The one who has dipped his hand into the bowl with me will betray me. The Son of Man will go just as it is written about him. But woe to that man who betrays the Son of Man! It would be better for him if he had not been born.” - [Matthew 26:24-24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026&version=NIV)

In twenty centuries, the Catholic Church has proclaimed many thousands of saints, but has never declared someone to be in hell.

> En vingt siècles d’histoire, l’Église a déclaré de très nombreux saints, mais n’a jamais donné le nom d’un seul damné. Pour pouvoir affirmer la condamnation éternelle d’une personne, il faudrait se placer en juge suprême... C’est pourquoi ni l’Église, ni aucun homme ne peut condamner une personne, même si celle-ci a commis dans sa vie tous les plus graves péchés possibles. - [Judas est-il en enfer?](https://qe.catholique.org/la-mort-et-l-au-dela/7128-judas-est-il-en-enfer)

Erasmus believed that Judas was free to change his intention, but Martin Luther argued in rebuttal that Judas' will was immutable. John Calvin states that Judas was predestined to damnation, but writes on the question of Judas' guilt: "surely in Judas' betrayal, it will be no more right, because God himself willed that his son be delivered up and delivered him up to death, to ascribe the guilt of the crime to God than to transfer the credit for redemption to Judas." The Catholic Church has no view on his damnation. Catholicism  only proclaims individuals Eternal Salvation through the Canon of Saints. There is no **”Canon of the Damned”**, nor any official proclamation of the damnation of Judas.

Most believe that the infamous Judas is in hell, where he belongs! That said, there are a few that hold that Judas possibly repented  and is saved, such as Origen and St. Francis de Sales. However, Scriptures paint a very bleak picture of the individual.

> Judas Iscariot was one of the twelve disciples. Judas was the one who sold out Jesus to those who wanted to kill him. When thousands of people abandoned Jesus because His words were too difficult to believe, Judas stayed with him. He was a theif who stole money that was given to Jesus. Judas traveled across the region of Judea preaching the message of Jesus to the Israelites. While a disciple of Jesus, Judas probably performed miracles. Judas obviously believed something about Jesus or he would not have devoted over three years of his life to following Him. The combination of committed disciple and greedy betrayer causes many people wonder whether or not Judas was actually saved.
>
> The evidences for Judas’ salvation are not conclusive. Jesus said specifically that that doing miracles is not evidence of true salvation (Matthew 7:21-23). Belief in the existence of God is not enough, for even the devils believe. (James 2:19) Judas’ actions as a disciple are not necessarily proof of salvation nor was Judas’ betrayal of Jesus proof that he was unsaved. Peter denied Jesus (though he did not sell Him for money), but Peter later repented of his denial.
>
> When Judas betrayed Jesus he felt great remorse. Matthew 27:3 says that Judas repented himself, yet Judas’ repentance does not seem to have the hallmarks of saving repentance. His response seems to be an emotional sorrow, not a rejection of his sinful actions or choices. He was sorry that Jesus was going to be put to death, but not necessarily sorry that he had betrayed Jesus. The remorse of Judas did not lead him to repentance but to suicide.
>
> **"The Bible never gives a definite statement about the salvation of Judas, but Satan’s possession of Judas seems to strongly imply that he was not saved.** (John 13:27) Many Christians are agreed that a genuine believer can never be demon possessed. It seems extremely unlikely that God would allow Satan to take possession of one of His children. This is even more telling in the case of Judas when he contrasted with Peter. The evening before the crucifixion Jesus warned Peter, “Satan hath desired to have you that he may sift you as wheat.” But Jesus tells him, “I have prayed for thee, that thy faith fail not.”(Luke 22:31-32) Satan was actively working on Judas, but Jesus gives no indication of praying for Judas. Would the Good Shepherd who gives His life for His sheep neglect to protect one who was truly His own?
>
> Scripture gives no compelling reason to believe Judas was saved. Some have said we do not know the reality of a person’s heart, so we should not say if one was saved or not. While the compassionate Christian will be careful to avoid being overly dogmatic about the state of another’s soul, the Bible gives specific evidences of salvation. The evaluation of the Biblical evidence leads me to conclude Judas was probably not saved. My conclusion does not condemn him to hell, nor do I wish for Judas to burn in hell. A comparison of Judas’ life and choices to the Biblical evidence of salvation leads me to believe he was never saved. If Judas had of repented of his sin, the grace of God is great enough that even the betrayal of Jesus could have been forgiven. - [Was Judas Iscariot Saved?](https://everlastingtruths.com/2018/07/25/was-judas-iscariot-saved/)

Comment: Could you put the second quoted block in English?

Comment: @Kris The paragraph preceding the quote paraphrases it!

Comment: “The one who has dipped his hand into the bowl with me will betray me..."- this passage is not pointing to Judas, why? Judas was about to leave, and Jesus was the one who dipped the bread not Judas, the passage is more or less pointing to Peter, who definitely betrayed Jesus not only as "Son of Man" but Peter proclaimed "Jesus is the Messiah, Son of the Living God". Judas never saw Jesus as the "Son of Man", he only look upon Jesus as "Rabbi", and was not present during the oath of the Apostles to Jesus, not to betray him.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, based on various Biblical text and  the words of Jesus Christ Himself. According to Acts 1 starting at vs 16-26 it is explained that Judas had to be replaced so they drew lots for either "Joseph called Barsabbas who was also called Justus and Matthias. Matthias was chose to take the place of Judas.

Acts 1:25 states, "to occupy this ministry and apostleship from which Judas turned aside to go to his own place." I did some research on the meaning of "his own place." I believe Albert Barns thoroughly explains it here: https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/eng/bnb/acts-1.html Just scroll down to verse 25.

Jesus stated at Matthew 8:12, "but the sons of the kingdom shall be cast out into the outer darkness; in that place there shall be weeping and gnashing of teeth." At Matthew 25 Jesus speaks extensively about the kingdom and those who will not be apart of the kingdom. Verse 41, "Then He will also say to those on His left, Depart from Me accursed ones, into the eternal fire which has been prepared for the devil and his angels." And verse 46, "And these will go away into eternal punishment, but the righteous into eternal life."

Keep in mind Jesus pointed out that the lake of fire was not prepared for mankind but for the devil and his angels, who deserve it. Sinners who share in rebellion must also share in the punishment. Or to put this another way the "parallel" to eternal life in heaven is eternal punishment in hell.

There is no "annihilation" or after you die you cease to exist. Matthew 10:28, the words of Jesus. "And do not fear those who kill the body, but are unable to kill the soul; but rather fear Him who is able to destroy both soul and body in hell."

Jesus is explaining that those persecuting can only kill the body, not life itself (the soul here). Rather, they were to fear God who can judge both body and soul worthy of life with God. Gehenna is a lake of fire, the place where all nonbelievers will be condemned at the final judgment. Revelation 20:14-15.

Here are two what I call "comfort" verses to consider. Matthew 23:37, "O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, who kills the prophets and stones those who are sent to her! How often I wanted to gather your children together, the way a hen gathers her chicks under her wings, and you were unwilling."

2 Peter 3:9, "The Lord is not slow about His promise, as some men count slowness, but is patient toward you, not wishing for any to perish but for all to come to repentance."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130386/discussion-on-answer-by-mr-bond-is-judas-in-hell-for-eternity).